# Spark issue with the class generated from avro schema

Tags: serialization, apache-spark, avro

I have piece of code written in spark that loads data from HDFS into java classes generated from avro idl. On RDD created in that way I am executing simple operation which results depends on fact whether I cache RDD before it or not
i.e if I run code below

```
val loadedData = loadFromHDFS[Data](path,...)
println(loadedData.map(x => x.getUserId + x.getDate).distinct().count()) // 200000
```

program will print 200000, on the other hand executing next code

```
val loadedData = loadFromHDFS[Data](path,...).cache()
println(loadedData.map(x => x.getUserId + x.getDate).distinct().count()) // 1
```

result in 1 printed to stdout.

When I inspect values of the fields after reading cached data it seems

I am pretty sure that root cause of described problem is issue with serialization of classes generated from avro idl, but I do not know how to resolve it. I tried to use Kryo, registering generated class (Data), registering different serializers from chill_avro for given class (SpecificRecordSerializer, SpecificRecordBinarySerializer, etc), but none of those ideas helps me.

How I can solve this problem?

[Link](https://github.com/alberskib/spark-avro-serialization-issue) to minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: I ran into this same issue. Did you learn any more about it? Is it a known issue? If not, perhaps it should be reported to Spark?

Comment: To make it work you need to create deep copy of loaded data i.e `loadFromHDFS[Data](path,...).map(Data.newBuilder(_).build()).cache()` will do the job

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below out -

```
val loadedData = loadFromHDFS[Data](path,...)
println(loadedData.map(x => x.getUserId + x.getDate).distinct().count()).cache()
```